# Calculate the sum of multiple inputs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know questions of this nature have been asked on many occasions but after a few hours of trying out different things I am still none the wiser. Hopefully someone can enlighten me.

I am attempting to add the values of multiple inputs and output the total value in a separate field. The following snippet does the job but I need to loop through each season as they are dynamically created with different ids.

```
$('#season-0 .appearances').val(
    Number($('#season-4 .appearances').val()) +
    Number($('#season-36 .appearances').val())
);
$('#season-0 .goals').val(
    Number($('#season-4 .goals').val()) +
    Number($('#season-36 .goals').val())
);
```

I've tried a few different functions but nothing seems to be working, for example:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.appearances').each(function(){
    sum = sum + Number($(this).val());
});
$('#season-0 .appearances').html(sum);
```

I'd appreciate any help on this, it's been doing my head in for far too long now ;)

Here is the associated HTML:

```
<div id="season-0">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-index="appearances" class="appearances" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-index="goals" class="goals" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="season-4">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-index="appearances" class="appearances" value="25" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-index="goals" class="goals" value="4" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="season-36">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-index="appearances" class="appearances" value="19" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-index="goals" class="goals" value="8" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I see, you're trying to display the sum in the first input box, to do that you must use *val(sum)*, so here is the working solution:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.appearances').each(function(){
    sum += Number($(this).val());
});
$('#season-0 .appearances').val(sum);
```

Also, make sure you have properly linked the jQuery library.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ephws/

Comment: Thanks for your response but your suggestion doesn't seem to be working. I've included the HTML but am sure the HTML isn't causing a problem as my first example is working. I can see how that should work - to be honest this is really puzzling me.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that's worked a treat and saved me a few more hours of frustration.

Comment: @roofdog It's important to note that you shouldn't run this code twice, otherwise it will add the previous sum each time :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jack. I did run the code for other values, eg. '.goals' in place of '.appearances' and it did indeed add the previous sum each time. I fixed it by placing `var sum=0;` before each one but it felt quite dirty! Can you suggest a cleaner way of doing it? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: When you do $(".appearances").each() you are actually adding the value of the first input field. On the first run, this isn't a problem because the first field is empty. I would create a separate row section to display the result, such as a <span></span>.